# Differences between mkvirtualenv and virtualenv for creating virtual environments

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am new to Python virtual environments. Previously I was using the `virtualenv` command to create virtual environments, but I came across to a tutorial using `mkvirtualenv` to create a virtual environment.

What is the benefit of `mkvirtualenv` over `virtualenv`, and how they are different?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**virtualenv** is a tool that allows you to create isolated Python environments, which can be quite helpful when you have different projects with differing requirements.

**mkvirtualenv** is command under **virtualenvwrapper** which is just a wrapper utility around virtualenv that makes it even easier to work with.

For detailed ref:

1. http://www.silverwareconsulting.com/index.cfm/2012/7/24/Getting-Started-with-virtualenv-and-virtualenvwrapper-in-Python
2. https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @Abhijith Mg So in that case which one is the Ideal way to create virtual environment either virtualenv or mkvirtualenv ? Can we access the mkvirtualenv utilities/benefits after invoking virtual with virtualenv command or  mkvirtualenv is preferable over previous one.

Comment: There is no ideal way as such. Its just based on your project requirements. I personally use standalone virtualenv. If you go through the links which I have mentioned in the answer you will get a clear idea on what exactly u need.

Comment: Thanks abhijith for your view on "venv", I am wondering why I could not  find the first link which you have provided in reference to your answer. Its really  a simplest explanation what i was looking for. thanks again.

Comment: Np. Happy coding!

Comment: First link is no longer valid, but a snapshot from May 2017 still is: https://web.archive.org/web/20170515051828/https://www.silverwareconsulting.com/index.cfm/2012/7/24/Getting-Started-with-virtualenv-and-virtualenvwrapper-in-Python

Answer (score 0):

It used by a wrapper on `virtualenv`. It makes working on these environments easier since you can swap them by using `workon` command and they are stored in one place. [See this](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html).